# Regex matching hard returns in addition to white space

Tags: php, regex

The below matches when there's excess white space.  Now I need it to match regardless of what's in between it... I tried replacing `\s*` with `.+?` but that didn't work.  I'm looking at a regex cheat sheet and can't figure out the most efficient way to do this.

```
preg_replace("/<sup>(\s*)$key(\s*)<\/sup>/i", "<sup>$val</sup>", $text);
```

Should match: `<sup>(anything here){$key}(anything here)</sup>`

**update**

This is sad... I just realized the regex I'm working with doesn't need to match whitespaces, but a `<br>` tag... something like

`$text = preg_replace("/<sup>([\s\n(<br>)]*)$key([\s\n(<br>)]*)<\/sup>/is", "<sup>$val</sup>", $text);`

Comment: Some input would be rather helpful.

Comment: When trying to design a regex, you must begin with a set of strings which *should* match and a set of strings which *should not* match - otherwise you cannot know if you have succeeded! And as FailedDev points out, it is helpful to share those strings when asking for help.

Comment: @Webnet no since you need this to match with nested elements etc. You should not use regex for this.

Comment: I only need to match whitespace and hard returns, but if possible any elements would've been great.  It's not an absolute requirement though

Comment: What in the world is a “hard return”?  There is no code point whose name is `HARD RETURN` — nor `SOFT RETURN` for that matter.

Comment: Soft return is a line return due to word wrapping, whereas a hard return is a user specified line return (ie - by pressing enter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand, but if you want `.*?` to also match newlines, you need the `/s` modifier:

```
preg_replace("#<sup>(.*?)$key(.*?)</sup>#is", "<sup>$val</sup>", $text);
```

Be aware though, that this might match more than you think. If you have more than one `<sup>` tag, and only the last one contains `$key`, the regex will match all the way from the first `<sup>` to the last `</sup>`! So better be specific about what you want to allow there.

I'd suggest you use `(?:(?!</?sup).)*` instead of `.*?` in the above regex. This ensures that you'll never match across tag boundaries:

```
(?:       # Try to match...
 (?!      #  (as long as it's impossible to match
  </?sup #   <sup or </sup
 )        #   at the current position)
 .        # ... any character.
)*        # Do this any number of times.
```

So, in the end, you get:

```
preg_replace("#<sup>(?:(?!</?sup).)*$key(?:(?!</?sup).)*</sup>#is", "<sup>$val</sup>", $text);
```

Comment: That's a good point... I will definitely have multiples.  What's the best way to fix that multiples issue?

Comment: That matched, but it matches too much.  It removed numerous `<sup>` tags and everything in between

Comment: @Webnet: I can't reproduce that here. Can you post the problematic piece of text?

Comment: How can I take the part removed just before `</sup` and add it after `</sup>` on what's replaced?

Comment: Try `preg_replace("#<sup>(?:(?!</?sup).)*$key((?:(?!</?sup).)*)</sup>#is", "<sup>$val</sup>\1", $text);`

Comment: Nope, I tried 1 through 4 and didn't work... I've also tried `$1` through 4.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know PHP. Perhaps you should create another question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
preg_replace("/<sup\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/sup>/i", "<sup>$val</sup>", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are searching for a specific word inside a sup element so that the sup element matches?

```
$result = preg_replace('%<sup[^>]*>.*?\b$key\b.*?</sup>%s', '<sup>$val</sup>', $text);
```

Then this should do. As @Tim Pietzcker and other will say, this will work with one sup. If you have nested sup elements you should not use regex.